# Spring Integration 6 - How to perform two task successively by SFTP: download files to local file storage, move files to another remote directory

Tags: spring, file, download, integration, sftp

I'm using Java 17 and spring-integration 6.0.3
I got a flow that successfully connects to remote server by sftp, recursively downloads all the files into local file storage keeping the source's folders structure

```
@Bean
public QueueChannelSpec remoteFileOutputChannel() {
    return MessageChannels.queue();
}

@Bean
IntegrationFlow flow(DefaultSftpSessionFactory sf) {
    return IntegrationFlow.fromSupplier(() -> "/upload/*", // remote dir
                    e -> e.poller(Pollers.fixedDelay(5000)))
            .handle(Sftp.outboundGateway(sf, AbstractRemoteFileOutboundGateway.Command.MGET, "payload")
                    .options(AbstractRemoteFileOutboundGateway.Option.RECURSIVE)
                    .fileExistsMode(FileExistsMode.IGNORE)
                    .localDirectoryExpression("'C:/downloadedFromRemote' + #remoteDirectory")) // re-create tree locally
            .split()
            .log()
            .channel("remoteFileOutputChannel")
            .get();
}
```

How could I change this in order to perform two operations:

1. copy the files in the local file storage (same as above-mentioned)
2. move the files to another location on the same remote server keeping the source's folders structure

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

I've tried to add another handler with AbstractRemoteFileOutboundGateway.Command.MV but still without success